# Solving the heat equation using Laplace Transforms

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve the 1-D heat equation using Laplace Transform theory. The equation is as follows. I don't have the capability to write the symbols so I will write it out.

```
                     partial u/partial t = 2(partial squared u/ partial x squared) -x 
  boundary conditions are partial u/partial x(0,t)=1, partial u/partial x(2,t)=beta.
```

$$
\partial u/\partial t = 2(\partial^2 u/ \partial x^2) -x,\partial u/\partial x(0,t)=1, \partial u/\partial x(2,t)=\beta
$$

The problem asks the following:

(a). For what value of beta does there exist a steady-state solution?

(b). if the initial temperature is uniform such that $u(x,0)=5$ and $\beta$ takes the value suggested by the answer to part (a), derive the equilibrium temperature distribution.

I was able to get an equation that looks like `U(x,s)=c e^(s/2)^1/2 -(1/s)((x/s)-u(x,0))`. But I am not sure how to go from here to solve for beta using the boundary conditions. I need some assistance from someone.

Comment: Is this a question about the _Mathematica_ software package?

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with your question. You specify that the first spatial derivative at the left end is 1. But then we can not have a uniform initial temperature of 5 because the derivative would be zero.